# how to determine current scale on iphone web page

Tags: javascript, iphone

You can set the inital-scale, but how do you get/set the current scale?

Comment: I found iScroll - it does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Objective-C like so:

```
[myUIWebView zoomScale];
```

There is no way to do this using Javascript, so unless you are implementing your own UIWebView, this is impossible.